# How to output meta_key in wp_postmeta?

Tags: meta-query, meta-value

I have a meta_key in wp_postmeta called _su_description.

How do I output its value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get post meta, then you just need to call `get_post_meta()` function and pass three arguments: current post id, your meta key and `true` value (what indicates that you want to receive only one value in return).

Simply call `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_su_description', true );` in your template and your meta value will be rendered.